# Drawing in PDF in Local Coordinate System

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am currently working with iTextSharp. I get some polygon cordinates from a file (location of each significant point) and trying to draw them in PDF. It is working great but problem is that the shape is always in bottom left corner on a page. It looks like this:

I don't want to change my data (it will be difficult and very problematic due to fact that I want to copy this shape 4 times on page) but I want to set local coordinate system in some place and then start drawing. Any ideas? Maybe another PDF C# library?

Comment: What is the link to the image? I'll edit your question to show it.

Comment: It's fairly simple to change the CTM (current transformation matrix), but as Alexis says: please clarify. Also: if you want to have 4 copies of the same data on the page, you certainly want to draw the shape to a `PdfTemplate` object and reuse that object. Why would you perform the same operations 4 times?

Comment: Link to image: http://www.pl.image-share.com/ijpg-207-294.html    I did not consider templates, but it seems like a good idea. I found solution in Java using AffineTransform and translate method on PdfContentByte object, but i couldn't find any equivalent in C#. I need to copy this polygon 2 maybe 4 times because it is contour of a PCB and I will place different components into every shape (polygon).

Comment: Sory for 2 comments in a row. Templates saves the day :) Thanks a lot. It is all I need i think. Now it looks like this: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/k97a.jpg And templaes can be scaled, rotated - great! Anyway it will be nice to know how to do this without template (or within template), because as you can see left and bot edge cut a little bit of a line.

Comment: It's great you found a way to resolve your problems. I would recommend, though, that you post a short answer to your question giving a sketch of the solution as former questions & answers on stackoverflow are meant to serve a a well of knowledge for anyone with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by code:

```
PdfTemplate tp = cb.CreateTemplate(width, height);
tp.MoveTo(oStartPoly.dStartX, oStartPoly.dStartY);
```

etc...
than you do like so:

```
cb.AddTemplate(tp, fScaleFactor, 0, 0, fScaleFactor, fX, doc.PageSize.Height / 3);
```

Within this method you can scale and set absolute location. 
The only problem is that line width is scaled too.